# React, how to assign a user to the button, to block a user?

Tags: reactjs

I got list of users and next to each user there is block button.
After clicking on a block button, a modal pops up asking for confirmation. When i confirm, specific user is being block.

Now i got displaying modal but after clicking on confirm button nothing happens.
I think I need to assign a user to the button?
Unlock button works, but it's not in a modal.

My code:

```
import MyModal from '@/views/MyModal'

function UsersList({ users, userId }) {
  function locking(pk, action) {
    axios.get(`/user/${pk}/${action}/`).then(() => {
      update()
    })
  }

  return (
          ...{users != null && users.length > 0 ? (
            users.map((profile) => {
              return (
                <tr key={profile.id} id={profile.id} className={userId === profile.id ? 'table-active' : ''}>
                  {showEntities && <td className='align-middle'>{profile.entity_name}</td>}
                  <td className='align-middle'>
                    {profile.first_name} {profile.last_name}
                    {!profile.active && (
                      <span className='ml-xl-2 badge badge-pill badge-secondary'>
                        <i className='fa fa-lock' /> Blocked
                      </span>
                    )}
                  </td>...
                    {profile.id !== userId && //to be sure to not block myself
                      (profile.active ? (
                        <button
                          type='button'
                          className='btn d-block btn-danger w-5rem mb-2 badge'
                          data-toggle='modal'
                          data-target='#MyModal'
                        >
                          Block
                        </button>
                      ) : (
                        <a
                          className='btn d-block btn-warning w-5rem mb-2 badge'
                          href='#'
                          onClick={() => {
                            locking(profile.id, 'unlock')
                          }}
                        >
                          Unblock
                        </a>
                      ))}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              )
            })
          ) : (
          
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <MyModal locking={locking()} />
    </div>
  )
}
export default UsersList
```

MyModal

```
export default function  MyModal({locking}) {
  return (
    <div className='modal fade' id='MyModal' tabIndex='-1' aria-labelledby='MyModal' aria-hidden='true'>
 ...
            <h5 className='modal-title' id='MyModal'>
              Are you sure to block this user?
            </h5>
            <button type='button' className='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>
              <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className='modal-footer'>
            <button type='button' className='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>
              <i className='fas fa-times mr-2' />
              Exit
            </button>
            <button
              type='button'
              className='btn btn-success'
              onClick={() => {
                locking      
              }}
            >
              <i className='fas fa-check-circle mr-2' />
              Confirm
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: There is no `onClick` callback associated with the block user button. Perhaps you should/could implement a click handler to store a profile id in state to be passed to the modal to block a user.

Comment: How can i do this? i'm not a react js programmer and so I don't know how :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

1. There is no click handler to block a profile
2. When passing `locking` to `MyModal` it is invoked immediately (`locking={locking()}`)
3. In the `MyModal` block button `onClick` callback `locking` *isn't* invoked (`() => { locking }`

## Solution

1. Add some state to `UserList` to store a user/profile id to block/unblock
2. Create a block callback to pass to the modal
3. Pass block callback to `MyModal`

UsersList

```
function UsersList({ users, userId }) {
  const [profileId, setProfileId] = useState(null); // <-- create id state

  function locking(pk, action) {
    axios.get(`/user/${pk}/${action}/`)
      .then(() => {
        update();
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setProfileId(null); // <-- clear state when done
      });
  }

  const blockId = () => locking(profileId, 'lock'); // <-- callback to block/lock

  return (
          ...
          {users != null && users.length > 0 ? (
            users.map((profile) => {
              return (
                <tr key={profile.id} id={profile.id} className={userId === profile.id ? 'table-active' : ''}>
                  ...
                  </td>
                    ...
                    {profile.id !== userId && //to be sure to not block myself
                      (profile.active ? (
                        <button
                          type='button'
                          className='btn d-block btn-danger w-5rem mb-2 badge'
                          data-toggle='modal'
                          data-target='#MyModal'
                          onClick={() => setProfileId(profile.id)} // <-- set id to block
                        >
                          Block
                        </button>
                      ) : (
                        <a
                          className='btn d-block btn-warning w-5rem mb-2 badge'
                          href='#'
                          onClick={() => {
                            locking(profile.id, 'unlock')
                          }}
                        >
                          Unblock
                        </a>
                      ))}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              )
            })
          ) : (
          
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <MyModal locking={blockId} /> // <-- pass blockId callback
    </div>
  )
}
```

MyModal

```
export default function  MyModal({locking}) {
  return (
    <div className='modal fade' id='MyModal' tabIndex='-1' aria-labelledby='MyModal' aria-hidden='true'>
      ...
            <button
              type='button'
              className='btn btn-success'
              onClick={locking} // <-- attach callback
            >
              <i className='fas fa-check-circle mr-2' />
              Confirm
            </button>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Now i see that i need to click block button two times to display modal.

Comment: @Jmaria Interesting. Think you could reproduce that into a simple codesandbox and link here?

Comment: I got this,  i had to delete "{profileId && " in UserList

Comment: @Jmaria Right on... TBH I wasn't entirely sure how your modal was being opened (since I didn't see an open prop passed), to me it appeared you are using bootstrap/react-bootstrap so I thought I had a 50/50 chance of guessing the correct direction. I'll update my answer.